# How to make android buttons switch different XML layouts?

Tags: android, xml, button, layout

I just started some android programming recently and I am creating a small project app. 
I have a few different XML Layout files and want my button to go to that layout. However, when I press the button on the emulator I get this message "Unfortunately "MyApp" Has stopped".

Here is my Main Activity Class:

```
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity; 
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.Button;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Shows the Activities screen.

    Button Button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Button1);
    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ActivityList.class);
             startActivity(i);

         }
     });
```

}

This is my XML CODE for the Button:

```
    android:id="@+id/Button1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Menutxt"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Menutxt"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/Choose_Activity"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:typeface="serif"
```

I was wondering if anyone could help me out here, been trying to do this for a few hours and cannot get past it. Thanks.

Comment: you need to register new activity in manifest.xml file, try googling that

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: Add this line in the AndroidManifest.xml file: 
<activity android:name=".ActivityList" /> under <application tag>

Comment: I have added that Line but it still says Unfortunately "MyApp" Has stopped.

Comment: This is the stack Trace: [2013-04-10 13:25:13 - SportsFitnessApp] Android Launch!
[2013-04-10 13:25:13 - SportsFitnessApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-04-10 13:25:13 - SportsFitnessApp] Performing com.example.sportsfitnessapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-04-10 13:25:13 - SportsFitnessApp] Uploading SportsFitnessApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-04-10 13:25:22 - SportsFitnessApp] Installing SportsFitnessApp.apk...
[2013-04-10 13:25:41 - SportsFitnessApp] Success!
[2013-04-10 13:25:41 - SportsFitnessApp] Starting activity com.example.sportsfitnessapp.MainActivity on device emula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the layout of the activity that you wish to open. it should go at the top: `tools:context=".activity" >`

e.g.
`<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal" 
       tools:context=".activity" >`

replace "activity" with the name of your activity

Answer (score 0):

You did not show us your ActivityList.class , maybe you have created and extends Activity, but make sure that in your AndroidManifest.xml has this code:

activity android:name=".ActivityList"